# Saving the output of array permutations into a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to save the permutation result of an array into a 2d array. let's say I have an array {1,2,3,4}, I created a 2D array with rows: N! and columns 4. Is it possible to save all the results into 2D array. For example I have the following output I want to save it into 2D array

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 3]

Comment: Yes it is possible just like you said : create a 2D array with 4! rows and 4 columns. Give it a try.

Comment: What is your question then? It seems you already know what you need to know?!

Comment: I am able to print them only not saving the output, my question is how can I save the output into 2D array

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Just in case you are wondering how to create and populate a "2D array" here's what I can tell :

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArraysOfArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is your '1D' array
        int[] init = {1, 2, 3, 4};

        //This is you '2D' array, 24 possibilities of 4 items in order
        int[][] combinations = new int[24][4];

        // fill your 2D array with the combinations you compute like that :
        combinations[0] = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
        combinations[1] = new int[] {1,2,4,3};
        combinations[2] = new int[] {1,3,2,4};
        combinations[3] = new int[] {1,3,4,2};
        combinations[4] = new int[] {1,4,2,3};
        combinations[5] = new int[] {1,4,3,2};
        //...
        combinations[23] = new int[] {4,3,2,1};

        // or you can assign the individual values one by one :
        combinations[0][0] = 1;
        combinations[0][1] = 2;
        combinations[0][2] = 3;
        combinations[0][3] = 4;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combinations[3]));   
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store many arrays in a "2D" array, then use a loop as follows:

```java
      int size = 24;  //this should be n! for permutations of n values.
      combs[][] = new int[size][];
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          combs[i] = getNextPermutationArray();
      }
```

And Java does not have true multidimensional arrays.  It simply has arrays of arrays of arrays, etc.